# C# WriteAllBytes() in the program path?

Tags: c#

i have excel file Embedded Resource , How can I create excel on Application.StartupPath?

```
public void openExcel()
    {

        //string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        string tempPath = Application.StartupPath; //ERROR is denied

        
        File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, Properties.Resources.myexcel);

        Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
        Excel._Workbook excelWorkbook;
        excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(tempPath);

        excelApplication.Visible = true;

    }
```

Comment: If you install your app to the Program Files folder, normal users no longer have access here by default and haven't for a long time now. This even includes administrators, unless they explicitly choose to elevate the program's process when it first starts up. That is, not having write access into your program's startup folder is the normal and expected way Windows has worked for more than 20 years now. Instead, look for the Application Data folder.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn _"more than 20 years"_ IIRC, that behavior started with Vista, not XP. Otherwise, solid advice.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine It actually started in Windows 2000, and it definitely was also in XP. However, few noticed or cared before Vista because at the time everyone either still ran as administrator or installed using Fat32 file system, which was still an option.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn No, I was referring to the part about having to elevate the process even if you're an administrator. I don't have a very good memory but I'm 98% sure you didn't have to do that in XP. But I see your point that from a development perspective, it shouldn't matter as long as some users won't have access anyway.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Oh yes, that was Vista. The restrictive file permission was 2000.

Answer (score 0):

[`Application.StartupPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is the path containing the executable file started.

If you want a temporary filename in the same directory, do

```
string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "temp.xls");
```

or similar.

However, using a temporary directory, as your commented code shows, would be better. There's no guarantee you can write to the executable's directory.

Comment: **GetPathRoot()** worked. `string tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetPathRoot(Application.StartupPath), "temp.xlsm");`

Comment: Well, GetPathRoot will get you the root directory, which you probably don't want.